# How can I save the foreign key in both the tables? - nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models with one-to-one relationship between them - RFP and Bid.
Here is the relevant code -

Rfp.hbm.xml:

```
<one-to-one name="Bid" class="Bid" property-ref="Rfp" />
```

Bid.hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one name="Rfp" class="Rfp" column="RfpId" not-null="true" />
```

Rfp.cs:

```
public virtual Bid Bid { get; set; }
```

Bid.cs:

```
public virtual Rfp Rfp { get; set; }
```

When I do the following -

```
bid.Rfp = Repository.Get<Models.Rfp>(command.BidDetails.RfpId);
Repository.SaveOrUpdate(bid);
```

The foregin key of RFP is saved in the Bid record, but the foreign key of Bid is not saved in the RFP record. As a result I can't get a particular RFP's bid by saying `bid.Rfp` - it returns null.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: in a one to one relationship there is only one foreign key. Are you saying that Rfp table has a foreign key to bid? If so why did you map it as one-to-one instead of many-to-one?

Comment: i followed this write up - http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one. One side of the two entities is declared many-to-one here. I am aware one-to-one relationships can be implemented with only one foreign key. I need a way where I can get the bid's RFP and the RFP's bid. I want both of these to work - `Bid.Rfp` and `Rfp.Bid`.

Answer (score 0):

expand the property

```
private Rfp rfp;
public virtual Rfp Rfp
{
    get { return rfp; }
    set {
        rfp = value;
        if (rfp != null && rfp.Bid != this)
            rfp.Bid = this;
    }
}
```